# character "5" repeated in text fields, and system freezes

Tags: keyboard

I am running Ubuntu 15.10, with the latest updates.

When I type in a text field (google search, type name of file, etc..) the number 5 gets typed on its own and it keeps repeating until I press ESC and when I try to continue typing the number 5 resumes filling in the text field.

I have tried to set the keyboard repeat to zero, but does not help.

This does not happen all the time, sometimes if I shut down the computer it then behaves normally when I restart it, other times the computer becomes useless because I cannot type in any of the text fields.

Thanks
Sal

Answer (score 4):

Hardware problem! Some piece of cruft is making the <kbd>5</kbd> key stick. Clean your keyboard or try another keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. I replaced the keyboard with a brand new one and the same thing happens at random times.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and is already reported. It seams it has a fix also but I think you have to upgrade your kernel. Read [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579190) for more info. @KamalMostafa has provided a linnk to patched kernel in the bug's thread. I hope that the Ubuntu 16.04.1 will have the fix included.