# Character “5” repeated in text fields

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

When I click in a text field, the number 5 gets typed on its own and it keeps repeating until I press ESC. This also impacts Thunderbird, by auto tagging messages (hot key 5.) This problem is intermittent.

I've changed keyboard to rule out a hardware issue, but the problem still persists.

I am running Lubuntu 16.04, with the latest updates.

I recognize that this question was [already raised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749920/character-5-repeated-in-text-fields-and-system-freezes). Unfortunately, I am new on here, so I could not comment, nor does the original question offer a suitable answer to this issue.

Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a bug and is already reported. It seems it has a fix also but I think you have to upgrade your kernel. Read [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579190) for more info. I hope that the Ubuntu 16.04.1 will have the fix included.

Comment: you should add this as an answer on the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749920/character-5-repeated-in-text-fields-and-system-freezes), so this one can be closed as a dupe.